# how to reduce the size of the window opened with cv2.imshow()?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on this code. I got a problem with the size of the windows showing 'lane1' and 'lane2'. they are so big and uncomfortable to work with. Does `opencv` have any function that makes it possible to control the size of windows.

PS: the code is about object detection on multiple ROIs. I'd like to count the number of vehicles showing on each line (that means I got to add some more steps on tracking)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detection1(y2,y1,x2,x1,name):
    roi=img[y2:y1,x2:x1] 
    blob= cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(roi, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)
    #showing information on the screen
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []
    for output in layerOutputs: 
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if classes[class_id] in allowed_objects:
                if confidence > 0.2:
                    center_x = int(detection[0]*(x1-x2)) #(x2-x1)=width
                    center_y = int(detection[1]*(y1-y2)) #(y2-y1)=height
                    w = int(detection[2]*(x1-x2))
                    h = int(detection[3]*(y1-y2))
    
                    x = int(center_x - w/2)
                    y = int(center_y - h/2)
    
                    boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                    confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                    class_ids.append(class_id)
    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)
    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            cv2.rectangle(roi, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,0), 1)
            cv2.putText(roi, label + " " + confidence, (x, y-15), font, 1, (255,255,255), 1)
    cv2.imshow(name,roi)
# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3.weights', 'yolov3.cfg')

classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()
allowed_objects=['car','truck','motorbike','bicycle','bus']

#loading video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Traffic_Trim.mp4')
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
#reading frames from video
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    detection1(y2=216, y1=1080, x2=1008, x1=1560,name='lane1')
    detection1(y2=216, y1=1080, x2=72, x1=984,name='lane2')
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) 
    if key==27:
        break

cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use `cv2.namedWindow` once before cv2.imshow and read about the possible flags/parameters in the opencv documentation.

Comment: `cv.resizeWindow`, _if_ the window was created to be resizable rather (WINDOW_NORMAL)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `cv.resizeWindow`, coupled with the `WINDOW_NORMAL` flag to `cv.namedWindow`.

That spares you from having to resize the image itself (with cv.resize) **and** it allows you to **resize the window with your mouse!**

```py
import cv2 as cv
some_image = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"))

cv.namedWindow("some window", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL) # explicit window creation
cv.imshow("some window", some_image)
cv.resizeWindow("some window", 200, 400)

cv.waitKey() # to run the GUI
```

[Available `cv::WindowFlags` in official documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d90/group__highgui__window__flags.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3)